# get jquery touch position every x milliseconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, touch, touch-event

is there a way to get the touch position in a touchmove event every x milliseconds and then execute a function, when the x-coordinate at the moment and the one at the start are differing e.g. 50px?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below ;

```js
$('document').ready(function() {

  var touch,
    action,
    diffX,
    diffY,
    endX,
    endY,
    startX,
    startY,
    timer,
    timerXseconds = 500, // Change to the Time(milliseconds) to check for touch position 
    xDifferenceX = 50, // Change to difference (px) for x-coordinates from starting point to run your function
    xDifferenceY = 50; // Change to difference (px) for y-coordinates from starting point 

  function getCoord(e, c) {
    return /touch/.test(e.type) ? (e.originalEvent || e).changedTouches[0]['page' + c] : e['page' + c];
  }

  function testTouch(e) {
    if (e.type == 'touchstart') {
      touch = true;
    } else if (touch) {
      touch = false;
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  function onStart(ev) {
    if (testTouch(ev) && !action) {
      action = true;
      startX = getCoord(ev, 'X');
      startY = getCoord(ev, 'Y');
      diffX = 0;
      diffY = 0;
      timer = window.setInterval(checkPosition(ev), timerXseconds); // get coordinaties ever X time
      if (ev.type == 'mousedown') {
        $(document).on('mousemove', onMove).on('mouseup', onEnd);
      }

    }
  }

  function onMove(ev) {
    if (action) {
      checkPosition(ev)
    }
  }

  function checkPosition(ev) {
    endX = getCoord(ev, 'X');
    endY = getCoord(ev, 'Y');
    diffX = endX - startX;
    diffY = endY - startY;
    // Check if coordinates on Move are Different than Starting point by X pixels 
    if (Math.abs(diffX) > xDifferenceX || Math.abs(diffY) > xDifferenceY) {
    //  console.log('Start is :' + startX + ' End is : ' + endX + 'Difference is : ' + diffX);
      $(this).trigger('touchend');

      // here Add your function to run...
    }

  }

  function onEnd(ev) {
    window.clearInterval(timer);
    if (action) {
      action = false;
      if (ev.type == 'mouseup') {
        $(document).off('mousemove', onMove).off('mouseup', onEnd);
      }
    }
  }

  $('#monitor')
    .bind('touchstart mousedown', onStart)
    .bind('touchmove', onMove)
    .bind('touchend touchcancel', onEnd);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#monitor {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  background: green;
}
.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  bottom: 0;
  background: white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 23px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='monitor'>
  <div class='box'>start here</div>
</div>
```

Read this [post](http://blog.mobiscroll.com/working-with-touch-events/) for a more detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a few functions.

- The first function is called when there is a movement of the touch event, this event stores the x and y of the touch in a separate variable.
- Then we have a function that runs every <kbd>X</kbd> miliseconds, this function gets the x and y from the move event and dispatches then to your code.
- Functions 3, 4 and 5 are used to handle the start, stop and cancel dragevents, and start/stop the second function:

```js
var timerid;
var x;
var y;
var tick = 0;

function handleStart(evt) {
  console.log("handleStart");
  evt.preventDefault();
  timerid = window.setInterval(timer, 50); // Replace 50 here with X
}

function handleEnd(evt) {
  console.log("handleEnd");
  evt.preventDefault();
  window.clearInterval(timerid);
}

function handleCancel(evt) {
  console.log("handleCancel");
  evt.preventDefault();
  window.clearInterval(timerid);
}

function handleMove(evt) {
  console.log("handleMove");
  evt.preventDefault();
  // Select last point:
  var point = evt.changedTouches[evt.changedTouches.length - 1];
  x = point.pageX;
  y = point.pageY;
}

function timer() {
  console.log("timer");
  tick++;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "tick: " + tick + " x: " + x + " y:" + y;
}


var el = document.getElementById("canvas");
el.addEventListener("touchstart", handleStart, false);
el.addEventListener("touchend", handleEnd, false);
el.addEventListener("touchcancel", handleCancel, false);
el.addEventListener("touchmove", handleMove, false);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300" style="border:solid black 1px;"></canvas>
<p id=output></p>
```

As long as the user is pressing the screen, the code will print out the x and the y coordinate to the screen. You can also integrate the reading of the x and y into your existing game loop instead of having a separate function if that is needed for your project.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io), it has exactly what you need. It supports "touchmove" called pan, that is being called every few milliseconds when you pan. Also there is a `threshold` property which determine a length in pixels you have to pan before recognizing it as a pan.